# why css3 only has + and ~ sibling combinator ? so how to solve this kindof?

Tags: css, css-selectors

```
<div class="box">
    <a><p>hello-1</p></a>
    <p>world</p>
    <a><p>hello-2</p></a>
</div>
```

I wanna use CSS3 makes when hover on `<a>`, only `<p>world</p>` would change color to red.

But, in CSS3, if use `div.box a:hover + p`, only works only hover on `hello-1`, `hello-2` not works.

`+` and `~` in CSS3 all are working for elements after that, Is there a way makes these two `<a>` could change `<p>world</p>` 's color when hover?

Comment: Question title does not reflect the actual question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
.box:hover > p { color: red; }
.box > p:hover { color: black; }
```

### [*live demo*](http://codepen.io/thebabydino/pen/afeti)

Comment: Tanks @Ana, it's cool. but why CSS3 didn't have a sibling combinator for completing this job?